# How can I detect changes to R's global environment during interactive execution?

Tags: r

I want to write a background program that detects changes to R's global environment and alerts the user if any variable is being overwritten (during an interactive session).

I've tinkered with the following code:

```r
environment_changed <- function(before_env, after_env) {
  !identical(before_env, after_env)
}

check_environment_change <- function(before_env) {
  after_env <- as.list(.GlobalEnv)
  if (has_environment_changed(before_env, after_env)) {
    print("Change detected!")
    }
  }

addTaskCallback(check_environment_change)

x <- 1
x <- 2 # doesn't work
```

It doesn't work. I do not really understand how `addTaskCallback` works, but I thought this might be one possible approach. How else might this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the example in `addTaskCallback()` as a template, I made the following. It uses the `times()` argument to identify how many times the additional callback will run (which I have currently set to `Inf`, so you'll have to shut it off with `removeTaskCallback()`.  What it currently does is check the environment for names that are the same before and after the execution of the task.  Then, it returns a message if any of those objects have changed.  Here's an example:

```r
times <- function(total = Inf, before_env = as.list(.GlobalEnv)) {
  ctr <- 0
  function(expr, value, ok, visible) {
    check_environment_overwrite <- function(before_env) {
      after_env <- as.list(.GlobalEnv)
      olaps <- intersect(names(before_env), names(after_env))
      if(length(olaps) > 0){
        if(!identical(before_env[olaps], after_env[olaps])){
          out <- lapply(seq_along(olaps), \(i){
            identical(before_env[[olaps[i]]], 
                      after_env[[olaps[i]]])})
          outv <- do.call("c", out)
          names(outv) <- olaps
            cat("The following elements have changed in .GlobalEnv: ", 
                names(outv)[which(!outv)], "\n", sep="")
          }
      }
    }
    check_environment_overwrite(before_env)
    before_env <<- as.list(.GlobalEnv)
    ctr <<- ctr + 1
    keep.me <- (ctr < total)
    if (!keep.me)
      cat("handler removing itself\n")
    
    # return
    keep.me
  }
}
```

To get the same result, start with a workspace that doesn't include `x` or `z`:

```r
# > n <- addTaskCallback(times())
# > x <- 1
# > z <- 1
# > x <- 2
# The following elements have changed in .GlobalEnv: x
# > z <- 1
# > z <- 2
# The following elements have changed in .GlobalEnv: z
# > 
# > removeTaskCallback(n)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

##### Edit: alternative assignment operator that checks overwriting beforehand

In the spirit of the question, the function above will notify you after you overwrote something.  We could make an alternative assignment operator that looks to see whether something will be overwritten and if it will be, it asks the user if they want to overwrite it.

```r
`%a%` <- function(lhs, rhs){
  lhs_name <- as.character(substitute(lhs))
  if(lhs_name %in% names(.GlobalEnv)){
   rpl <- askYesNo(paste0("Do you want to replace ", lhs_name, " in .GlobalEnv")) 
   if(rpl){
     assign(lhs_name, rhs, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   }
  }else{
    assign(lhs_name, rhs, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }
}
```

```r
# > x %a% 1
# > x %a% 2
# Do you want to replace x in .GlobalEnv (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
# > x
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, I learned a lot from your answer(s)! I also tried to overwrite `<-` in an early attempt, so it's very cool to see how you did it.

Comment: Glad to help.  I wasn't convinced it was going to be possible at first, but as I say to my students all the time - everything is possible in R; it comes down to a matter of motivation and resolve.